# Javascript: Trigger only parent div content within a duplicated list

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS. I am learning to apply event listeners, node lists but struggling with the JavaScript syntax for this query. I want to extract the innerHTML of each button to their corresponding textbox within the parent div. So if a user clicks button 3 for example, only textbox 3 value should read the innerHTML of button 3. As you can see, the event listener to trigger each button is working but struggling with the textboxes.

```js
let buttoninput = document.querySelectorAll(".buttoninput");
let textbox = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");

buttoninput.forEach(btnclickevent => {
    btnclickevent.addEventListener('click', () => {

        textbox.forEach(content => {

            content.value = btnclickevent.innerHTML;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 5</button>
    </div>
```

I am aware you can create an id for each textbox input and button and create individual rules but I want to avoid that route as this would be a long line of code. Right now the list is 5 but if I duplicated say 10 or 20 times, I would want the syntax to only trigger each parent div content regardless of the number of duplicates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find sibling of button by `parentNode.children[0]` as

```
btnclickevent.parentNode.children[0].value = btnclickevent.innerHTML;
```

```js
let buttoninput = document.querySelectorAll(".buttoninput");
let textbox = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");

buttoninput.forEach(btnclickevent => {
    btnclickevent.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btnclickevent.parentNode.children[0].value = btnclickevent.innerHTML;
        //textbox.forEach(content => {

        //    content.value = btnclickevent.innerHTML;
        //});
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 5</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent [check doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp)  property to get the div, the get it children [check doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp), and edit the textbox.
I apologies for not giving a code, but it should work nicely

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `parentElement` to get to the neighbouring input!

```js
let buttoninput = document.querySelectorAll(".buttoninput");

buttoninput.forEach(btnclickevent => {
    btnclickevent.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let textbox = btnclickevent.parentElement.querySelector(".textbox");
        textbox.value = btnclickevent.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

```html
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
        <button class="buttoninput">Button 5</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) to get access to access the `input` element. just make sure you pass in the event as an argument to the listener callback.

(Note: it's used twice as the previous node to the button is `#text`. The *next* one up is the input element.)

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttoninput");

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const prev = e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    prev.value = e.target.textContent;
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
  <button class="buttoninput">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
  <button class="buttoninput">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
  <button class="buttoninput">Button 3</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
  <button class="buttoninput">Button 4</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="textbox" value="">
  <button class="buttoninput">Button 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Andy for your answer!